# Bash obtain multiple number from result

Tags: bash, shell, random

I have these variables maybe this can up until 100 ( minimun two variables)
(Maximun +50)

```
1=10
2=21
3=44
4=36
...
```

and need find which variables sum up to `57`
In this case is variable 4 + 2.
Or maybe the result was `90` and this case is 1+3+4.

I think need some random code, maybe some like this.

```
#!/bin/bash
array[0]=10
array[1]=21
array[2]=44
array[3]=36
Next add random until this fits to result
```

But but if I have 100 variables and need to find a result is it possible?
I read some links to randomize but I never seen anything like this.

Comment: I can assure you, you don't want try to add variables at random until you may end up with the correct result. A structured approach would be way better. ¶ Also, please specify how many (minimum and maximum) values can be added to obtain the result.

Comment: One thing you could try is to substract the largest number that is smaller than your total.  Then do that again with the remainder and the other numbers.

Comment: You could use a sort algorithm approach. Like a Bubble-sort for example. Move along the array of values grouping, adding and asking if the sum reach the result you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for adding more information, however I wanted to know if it was ok to add more than two variables together to obtain 57. Likewise, would it be ok to "add" only one single variable if that variable already had value 57.

Comment: Yes this could happend ( 3 or  more variables in the same result) ,
When  the result is a variable is easy whit and if and loop.
`if [ var8random) = 57 ] them;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recursive Bash function tries to find and print sums using a brute-force, check all possible sums, approach:

```
function print_sums
{
    local -r target=$1              # Number for which sums are to be found
    local -r pre_sum=$2             # Sum built up for an outer target
    local -r values=( "${@:3}" )    # Values available to use in sums

    if (( target == 0 )) ; then
        printf '%s\n' "$pre_sum"
    elif (( ${#values[*]} == 0 )) ; then
        :
    else
        # Print any sums that include the first in the list of values
        local first_value=${values[0]}
        if (( first_value <= target )) ; then
            local new_pre_sum
            [[ -z $pre_sum ]]   && new_pre_sum=$first_value \
                                || new_pre_sum="$pre_sum+$first_value"
            local new_target=$((target - first_value))
            print_sums "$new_target" "$new_pre_sum" "${values[@]:1}"
        fi

        # Print any sums that don't include the first in the list of values
        print_sums "$target" "$pre_sum" "${values[@]:1}"
    fi

    return 0
}
```

Example usage, with an extended list of possible values to use in sums is:

```
values=(10 21 44 36 85 61 69 81 76 39 95 22 30 4 29 47 80 18 40 44 )
print_sums 90 '' "${values[@]}"
```

This prints:

```
10+21+30+29
10+44+36
10+36+22+4+18
10+36+4+40
10+36+44
10+76+4
10+22+18+40
10+4+29+47
10+80
21+36+4+29
21+69
21+39+30
21+22+29+18
21+22+47
21+4+47+18
21+29+40
61+29
39+22+29
39+4+29+18
39+4+47
```

It takes less than a second to do this on an oldish Linux machine.  However, the exponential explosion (each addition to the list of values doubles the potential number of sums to try) means that it is not a practical solution for significantly larger numbers of values.  I haven't tried 50, but it's hopeless unless the target value is small so you get a lot of early returns.

The question asked for the indices of the values in the sum to be printed, not the values themselves.  That can be done with minor modifications to the code (which are left as an exercise for anybody who is interested!).